# Order of the group containing $a^m$ and $a^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Given that $G=\langle a\rangle$, I have to find the order of $\langle a^m,a^n\rangle$. Now I know that $\langle a^m, a^n\rangle = \langle a^{\gcd(m,n)}\rangle$. Also my book says that the order of this group is $lcm(|a^m|,|a^n|)$.
I don't know how they got this. The way I tried was : order of the group = order of the generator = $|a|/\gcd[|a|,\gcd(m,n)]$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at MSE; e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256782/langle-xn-rangle-cap-langle-xm-rangle-langle-x-lcmm-n-rangle?rq=1) and related ones.

Comment: Actually I started wondering about this after realizing that where there is gcd involved in the generator, the order involves lcm and vice versa. But I don't know how to prove this.